# Sequence Involving Dirichlet Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

The question I have to prove is the following:

> Let $D(x)$ be Dirichlet Function:

$$D(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\in \Bbb Q \\ 0 & x \notin \Bbb Q \end{cases}$$

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{n\to\infty}$ be a convergent sequence.
>
> Determine if $(a_n) + D(a_n)$ is convergent.

I have a feeling that I can find an example the contradicts it, but I wasn't able to. Maybe The statement is correct?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Since $(a_n)$ is convergent, $(a_n + D(a_n))$ converges if and only if $(D(a_n))$ converges. That happens if and only if - what?

Comment: You're saying that a sum of a convergent and non-convergent is always non-convergent?

Comment: Yes. The sum and difference of convergent sequences are convergent. So if the sum of two sequences converges, and one of the two summands converges, the other must converge too.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. Basically you're saying that the statement is not true, since Diriclet does not converge.

Comment: Your claim can be proven from limit arithmetic easily, right? $\lim (a_n)+\lim(b_n)=\lim(a_n+b_n)$.

Comment: Yes, it's just limit arithmetic. And I say that _in general_ the sequence $(a_n + D(a_n))$ is not convergent, but there is a simple criterion telling you exactly when it converges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\lim a_n$.

If the sequence $a_n$ has finitely many rational numbers,
$$\lim [a_n+D(a_n)]=L+1$$

If it has finitely many irrational numbers,
$$\lim [a_n+D(a_n)]=L$$

Otherwise, $a_n+D(a_n)$ does not converge, because it has a subsequence that converges to $L$ and another subsequence that converges to $L+1$.